# What ASP.NET permissions do I need to access a serial port?

Tags: .net, asp.net, serialization, permissions, serial-port

I am working on a asp.net application and I want it to communicate to a arduino board via a serial port.  I created a windows application that could do that and it worked, but when I use the same code on my asp.net application, I get an exception that says that "Access to the port COM7 is denied".  Now I have been surfing the net for an answer, I came across a forum where they were talking about granting permissions to asp.net by using impersonation.  I am very new at using the .net framework and serial port.  If anyone can help, please do or maybe post a link that might be helpful.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.net uses a specific user account on your computer. Just like your main account you log in with. That user account has no permissions to do anything with the hardware.

To impersonate the other account in ASP.net you do the following:

Create an account that has all of the same permissions that the web user does, then in the web.config file add the following code in between the configuration tags

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="somedomain\newUser" password="newUsersPassword" />
```

Comment: I don't think this is entirely accurate, by default (up to IIS 7.5 at least) Application Pool Identity ran as a [NetworkService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx).  The documentation states the Network service has "Any privileges assigned to users and authenticated users."  In full trust it should be perfectly capable of interacting with hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class to do this communication.  The documentation for it states

> **SecurityPermission**
>   for the ability to call unmanaged code. Associated enumeration: UnmanagedCode

[Some more MSDN documentation about ASP.NET and security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649312.aspx)

> If your application calls unmanaged code, it must run with Full trust. Even the least restrictive partial trust level, High, does not permit calls to unmanaged code.

[You can configure the ASP.NET application's trust level like so.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649312.aspx#paght000017_step3)

[Wrapping Privileged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649312.aspx#paght000017_wrappingprivilegedcode) section suggests a workaround for granting full trust to your whole application (which could be a security risk).

Answer (score -1):

Try open connection and close connection on serial port block command.
Ex

```
 SerialPort COM = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM14");
protected void btnRele1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    COM.Open();
    if (btnRele1.BackColor != Color.Green)
    {
        COM.WriteLine("1");
        btnRele1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        btnRele1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        btnRele1.Text = "Rele 1 - ON";
    }
    else
    {
        COM.WriteLine("2");
        btnRele1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        btnRele1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        btnRele1.Text = "Rele 1 - OFF";
    }
    txtSerial.Text = COM.ReadLine();
    COM.Close();
}
```

Comment: Its not relevant to the question!