# Serial communication for Arduino through website

Tags: c#, asp.net, serial-port, arduino, communication

I am working on a project which deals with Arduino. We developed a forms application in C# for navigating a car. Navigation in forms application works correctly, without any problems.

Here is the corresponding code for driving the car (this is the whole forms application).

http://pastebin.com/5JuuyUh7

ASP.NET website is unable to communicate with Arduino. Pressing any button to navigate the car does not work.

http://pastebin.com/MnjHVMHd

Comment: Is this website hosted on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, website is hosted on local machine - rebuilded in visual studio. Arduino is connected to comport 8. Forms application works, website loads but clicking on a button does not work.

Comment: Looks like the COM8 port is not opened through website. Why?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820288/what-asp-net-permissions-do-i-need-to-access-a-serial-port)? Because it looks like exact copy of yours.

Answer (score 2):

You realise you need to either re-open the serial port with every request, or store the serial port object in the session & retrieve it at the start of every request?

From your code, clicking any button won't do anything because the serial port isn't open, or in the case of button2, open but nothing is sent.

Despite what it looks like, asp.net is not stateful. You need to rebuild the state everytime

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Now we are opening the port with every click, and it's working.
Thank you again.