# Strange behaviour when calling VB6.0 COM-component in C# (in python all is ok)

Tags: .net, com, vb6

I have some problems when working with COM-component in C#.

I have old (~2001-2003year developed) VB6 COM component, and unfortunately there is no source code for it. The component interacting with a service program (no source too). The main Application is written in VB6, and now I'm rewriting it on .Net.

I have imported (with TblImp) component into C# and calling it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text; 
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using SrvCommDCG;

class Program
{ 
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() == ApartmentState.STA)
        {
        System.Console.WriteLine("calling com");
        clsCommDCGService srv = new clsCommDCGService();
        srv.Check();
        System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm running it on Windows 7, nothing happens (the component should show a messagebox when check is finished).
When I'm running it on Windows 8, program crashes without any exception.

I've tried different thread models: MTA, STA (using either `[STAThread]`, or `SetApartmentState()`), calling `DisableComObjectEagerCleanup()` -- nothing helped.

After week of no result, I've tried to use my component in Python, and:

```python
import win32com.client
tst = win32com.client.Dispatch("SrvCommDCG.clsCommDCGService")
tst.Check()
```

All is working, check is ok and MessageBox appeared.

Ofc, it works from VB 6.0 too.

I think, the problem is that python is single-threaded win32 app, and C# is multithreaded managed code. And I'm missing some point to understand what I should add to C# code, to make it work? Unfortunately I need to call it from .Net.

edit #1: I've tried on .Net 4.0 and 4.5, and also on .Net 2.0 frameworks

edit #2: when program crashing on Windows 8 there aren't any useful messages (even if i ran program from VS C# debugger), it's just write "Program occured a problem and will be closed" (have russian Win8, can't tell you the exact message in Windows). The Event log in Win8 says: Process was killed due to unhandled exception c0000005 at address 012E72CC. It's simple Access Violation.

edit#3: While C# program works bad on Win7/8, it works normal on Windows XP. Mysterios things.

Comment: what's in the windows logs?

Comment: Does it work if you just add a reference to it, instead of using tblimp?

Comment: @PreetSangha When program crashing on Windows 8 there aren't any useful messages (even if i ran program from VS C# debugger), it's just write "Program occured a problem and will be closed" (have russian Win8, can't tell you the exact message in Windows).

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Tried both variants and had same results.

Comment: what about the windows logs (event viewer)? Have you checked UAC? 32 bit .net program?

Comment: @PreetSangha I've thought about UAC, but I'm running python script from the same user, and it works. I've tried to run C# code with administrative privileges and had no result under Windows 7 and crash under Windows 8.

Comment: @PreetSangha wow, I've checked the event log and saw that the application is closed cause of "unhandled exception" c0000005 at address 012E72CC. It's simple Access Violation, but why it happens only in C#/.Net?

Comment: Is your C# project located on a network share? Can you access COM ports from C# with `SerialPort`?

Comment: @GSerg. No. And why you asking about serial ports, when I'm talking about Common Object Model components?

Comment: @key Because I thought `SrvCommDCG.clsCommDCGService` has something to do with serial ports. What is the component actually supposed to do?

Comment: @Gserg, It working with fieldbus (ProfiBus). And you're right, I think it may use some functionality with serial ports. I will try to find what exact ports it uses and check can I access them with C# SerialPort. But still wondering how it can affect working of COM-component. :(

Comment: @key Because .NET framework has additional security checks that other environments might not have. E.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5820726/11683 (might even solve your problem).

Comment: @GSerg I've check service and it seems it opens COM-ports. Also, my C# app is able to work with COM ports. Now reading about SecurityPermissions, thanks, hope it will help.

Comment: You are breaking the contract for [STAThread], such a thread must pump a message loop.  Taken care of by the Python runtime for example.  But in C# you have to call Application.Run() yourself.  Seeing code you don't have source for dying with AccessViolation on later operating systems is a very strong hint that keeping this ancient code alive is probably a bad idea.  The warranty on it ran out a long time ago.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately I have to make this code works and after it i can try to reverse or smth to make a complete rewrite of a system. But I wonder, what else I should do to make a correct message pump? I've already tried to run code from Form (whish is instantiated via Application.Run(new Form(...)), but the result was the same.

Comment: @key - Would it be cheaper in the long run to just decompile the code and see if you can decypher it?